# Compare two lists of words and save the words that are not on the second list in perl

Tags: list, perl, compare

I have tried everything to make a list of words that exist uniquely to one file when compared to another file.  I put some debug printing in the code to find out where it was going and discovered that the code never does anything in the comparison loop.

I figure I am blind or overlooking something really obvious - someone please point out what is wrong and enjoy laughing at my "probably a novice" error.

```
while (<IN>) { #read the file

    chomp;

    $_ = lc; #convert to lower case
    s/ -- / /g; #remove double hyphen dashes
    s/ - / /g; #remove single hyphen dashes
    s/ +/ /g; #replace multiple spaces with one space
    s/[~`@#$%^&*-+=<>.,:;?"!_()\[\]]//g; #remove punctuation

    @hwords = split;
#   foreach $w (@hwords) { print  "$w \n";}

}
while (<IN0>) { #read the file

    chomp;

    $_ = lc; #convert to lower case
    s/ -- / /g; #remove double hyphen dashes
    s/ - / /g; #remove single hyphen dashes
    s/ +/ /g; #replacxew multiple spaces with one space
    s/[~`@#$%^&*-+=<>.,:;?"!_()\[\]]//g; #remove punctuation

    @awords = split;
#    foreach $w (@awords) {print "$w\n";}

}

$count =0;

@unique = ();

print "got here!\n"; # YES - it gets here

foreach  $w (@hwords) { print  "$w \n";}

foreach  $h (@hwords) {

    $x=1;
    print "got there!\n"; # NOPE, doesn't get here
    foreach $a (@awords) {
    if ($h eq $a) {
        $x=0;
        print "equals\n";  # NEVER see this
    }
    }
    if ($x eq 1) {
    ++$count;
    @unique = @unique, $h;
    print "$count, $h\n";  # NEVER see this, either
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that to display your code properly, you need to indent it in the editor window with 4 spaces. I've edited this one for you

Comment: I would recommend `perltidy` as well, for getting indentation consistent.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, each iteration of the loop replaces `@hwords` and `@awords` completely. So, in the end, both `@hwords` and `@awords` will contain only the words from the last line of each respective file.

You only need to pick up the words from the first file anyway. Then, while reading the second file, you compare its words against the stored words from the first file.

So, in the first loop, instead of setting `@hwords`, make it a lookup hash:

```
$hwords{$_} = 1 for split;
```

Now, after the first file has been read, all of its words are the keys of the `%hwords` hash.

Then, when reading the second file, in the second loop, look up each word in the lookup hash:

```
print "Word not found: $_\n"
    for grep { !$hwords{$_} } split;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a FAQ, the solution can be found in the FAQ.

[perldoc -q intersect](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-compute-the-difference-of-two-arrays%3F-How-do-I-compute-the-intersection-of-two-arrays%3F)

My thanks to @Botje on #perl on irc.freenode.net for reminding me of this.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this:

```
 use Array::Utils qw(:all);

 my @a = qw( a b c d );
 my @b = qw( c d e f );

 #get items from array First list that are not in array Second List
 my @notinsecond = array_minus( @b, @a );

 #get items from array Second list that are not in array First List
 my @notinfirst = array_minus( @a, @b );


 print join "\n",  @notinfirst;
 print join "\n",  @notinsecond;
```